# NSData arithmetic

Tags: objective-c, hex, nsdata

I have an `NSData` object of varying length, and what i want to do is grab every 2nd byte, and sum them all together into a new `NSData` object.

how would I do this?

I have found this method:
`enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock` but don't know how to do the arithmetic.

for example, I have this data: `37 64 61 31 33 61 36 38 61 39 39 37 36 34 39 36 30 34 36`

I want to sum all these values: `64 31 61 38 39 37 34 36 34`

and end up with this result: `02 3C`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumption: You want to sum multiple unsigned 8-bit values into a single unsigned 16-bit value, ignoring overflow.

```
NSData *data = ...;
const uint8_t *p = (const uint8_t *)[data bytes];
NSUInteger length = [data length];
uint16_t total = 0;
for (NSUInteger i = 1; i < length; i += 2)
    total += (uint16_t)p[i];
NSLog(@"total=%u", (unsigned)total);
```